# Docker container build Visual Studio solution

Tags: docker, configuration, containers, visual-studio-2019

I have a situation where I have multiple projects in one solution. I am working in Visual Studio 2019, C#. Some projects are WEBApi, basically backend projects. And I need to "put" just those projects in one Container.

I was able to make one project to run in a container, but can't make multiple projects to be in that same container, I have added a Docker support to the project, and it works just fine.

I have multiple configurations, one of them is Backend, which builds only backend projects.

So, my question is how to make Docker use solution configuration to build a container?